# Tkinter GUI Builder

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, builder

There are a number of Tkinter builders out there but none (that I've found) that work for Python 3. I don't have the time to learn Tkinter and don't use it much which is why I'm looking for a builder.

Comment: Why do you need to use Python 3?

Comment: My script has been built to work in py3, now i would like to add a GUI for it

Comment: in 2017 there at least 2 great option to generate tkinter code from a generator:  we can use Page (it needs active TCL to run) or pygubu : see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142194/is-there-a-gui-design-app-for-the-tkinter-grid-geometry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, pity I didn't get any useful responses. Fortunately I have discovered a solution. PyQt4 may not be Tkinter but it works just the same ... and works in python 3.x and comes with a GUI designer that is very neat. Takes a bit of research to know how to use it but well worth it

Comment: you may not have gotten any answers because most tk developers find tk easier to use by manually laying everything out. With a GUI builder you are limited to whatever is implemented in the UI.

Comment: PySide is a free alernative if you are interested

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is PySide compatible with Python 3? Also cx_freeze (the only binary compiler currently compatible with py3) can compile with PyQt4. Would PySide also be compatible with cx_freeze?

Comment: They seem to be distributing windows binaries for python 3.2 and other platforms here : http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:LanguageBindings::PySide::Downloads. Their FAQ seems to say it doesn't work for Python 3, though it seems dated. I have no idea about cx_freeze

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Python and have decided to use 3.x as well.  Might as well be up to speed on the future rather than the past. ;)  I also spent weeks playing around with different environments that fit my needs - gui builder, support for sql.  I ended up going with PyQT and Eric5 as the IDE.  So far I'm pretty pleased with it.

Eric5 can be found here: http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/eric-download.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an online GUI builder for Python:

[www.python-gui-builder.com](http://www.python-gui-builder.com)

It's not super-comprehensive--not all widgets are available to use.  However, on the upside, it requires no software download/installation.  Also, code for the GUI is generated in real-time and shown in a column on the right.

If you just need a very quick and easy GUI for Python, you can't beat it.

Answer (score 0):

PAGE is a drag-and-drop GUI generator for Python and Tkinter.
Latest version is Page 7.4 and works on py3
[*PAGE sourceforge link*](https://sourceforge.net/projects/page/)

Use the widget toolbar to drag and drop widgets, a handy attribute window sets the attributes.it saves work as .tcl file and you can genrate python code with a click
the installation comes with a tutorial that covers almost all tkinter widgets that can be used.

Page also has a discord  [*server invite link*](https://discord.com/invite/V6zCcjq) with support community